# Python Exception Handler variable e gives an unsupported operand type when printed

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to trap all exceptions in a piece of code and write it to a flat log file, but I keep getting this error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'long' and 'str' however I handle it. Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
            main(sys.argv[1:])
    except Exception as e:
            # write error to log file:
            print str(e)
            report = "ERROR" + e.message
            fh = open("/home/user/logs/error.log", 'a')
            fh.write(report)
            fh.close
```

It gives me this error if I try to print e or e.message or if I try to write e or e.message to the file!

Comment: So what exception type is `e` and perhaps you should try and convert `e.message` to a string first?

Comment: What is the **full traceback** of the exception? Nowhere are you concatenating a long to a string where the long integer is the left-hand operand.

Comment: And a side note: `fh.close` doesn't do anything but look up the method. You are not actually *calling* it. Use `fh.close()`.

Comment: i actually get the same error with e.message and e.args as well!

Comment: Where exactly is the exception? on `fh.write(report)`?

Comment: @FightFireWithFire: in any case, `str(e)` should be enough for most uses. But your error is clearly somewhere else. Again, what is the full traceback?

Comment: 'ERROR: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'long' and 'str' is all I am getting @MartijnPieters - i think the handler itself is truncating the output of the traceback but it seems to be the fh.write(report)

Comment: @FightFireWithFire: right, then your handler **works**. See that `ERROR` in front? You are handling the exception properly. Not sure what your problem is now. Is the problem that the traceback is not logged with it?

Comment: or for example:     
    fh.write(e)  generates 
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Answer (score 1):

A little testing showed that this problem comes up, if the exception message was only a number.

This can easily be fixed (as some commenters already suggested) by using `str(e)`. In the following code changed that, fixed also `fh.close()` call, and added a new line character because your would otherwise get only one line in your logfile.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main(sys.argv[1:])
    except Exception as e:
        # write error to log file:
        print str(e)
        report = "ERROR: " + str(e) + "\n"
        fh = open("/home/user/logs/error.log", 'a')
        fh.write(report)
        fh.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write the following line instead of using "+" operation with str and long

```
print("ERROR: %s" % e)
```